# Bit shift whole block of memory efficiently

Tags: c++, memory

I have following code, after performing a sobel operation:

```
short* tempBufferVert = new short[width * height];
ippiFilterSobelVertBorder_8u16s_C1R(pImg, width, tempBufferVert, width * 2, dstSize, IppiMaskSize::ippMskSize3x3, IppiBorderType::ippBorderConst, 0, pBufferVert);
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
    tempBufferVert[i] >>= 2;
```

The frustrating thing is, the bit shift is the longest taking operation of it all, the IPP sobel is so optimized it runs faster than my stupid bit shift. How can I optimize the bitshift, or are there IPP or other options (AVX?) to perform a bitshift on the whole memory (but pertain the sign of the short, which the >>= does on the Visual Studio implementation)

Comment: You can try adding a `short* bufPtr = tempBufferVert;` Then incrementing the `bufPtr` pointer in the loop instead of using the `[i]` operator. I can not guarantee it is going to be faster but that's one thing I would try.

Comment: What is the type of `width`/`height`, can they be aliases by `tempBufferVert` ? Have you look at generated asm of your loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ optimisers perform a lot better with iterator-based loops than with indexing loops.

This is because the compiler can make assumptions about how address arithmetic works at the index overflow. For it to make the same assumptions when using an index into an array you must happen to pick the correct datatype for the index by luck.

The shift code can be expressed as:

```
void shift(short* first, short* last, int bits)
{
  while (first != last) {
    *first++ >>= bits;
  }
}

int test(int width, int height)
{
  short* tempBufferVert = new short[width * height];
  shift(tempBufferVert, tempBufferVert + (width * height), 2);

}
```

Which will (with correct optimisations enabled) be vectorised: https://godbolt.org/g/oJ8Boj

note how the middle of the loop becomes:

```
.L76:
        vmovdqa ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [r9+rdx]
        add     r8, 1
        vpsraw  ymm0, ymm0, 2
        vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [r9+rdx], ymm0
        add     rdx, 32
        cmp     rsi, r8
        ja      .L76
        lea     rax, [rax+rdi*2]
        cmp     rcx, rdi
        je      .L127
        vzeroupper
```

Comment: Good, but I think the claim regarding iterators versus indexing is a red herring - I tried an array-indexing version of `shift` and it generated identical code to your iterator version (with gcc 6.3). Most modern compilers happily transform iterator/pointer-based loops to/from array-indexed loops unless there are aliasing issues which prevent it.

Comment: @PaulR not just aliasing issues - also the characteristics of the word size of the index variable. There's a cppcon2016 talk on it.

Comment: Yes, good point - I tend to use `size_t` or `ssize_t` for the index variable - using `int` can be less efficient in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure you are compiling with optimisation enabled (e.g. `-O3`), and then check whether your compiler is auto-vectorizing the right shift loop. If it's not then you can probably get a significant improvement with SSE:

```
#include <emmintrin.h> // SSE2

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i += 8)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&tempBufferVert[i]);
    v = _mm_srai_epi16(v, 2); // v >>= 2
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&tempBufferVert[i], v);
}
```

(Note: assumes `width*height` is a multiple of 8.)

You can probably do even better with some loop unrolling and/or using AVX2, but this may be enough for your needs as it stands.